# use of static keyword in c or c++

Tags: c++, c

This is a general C or C++ code related question. Why would you need the static keyword for a global variable in C or C++ if it is already global throughout the program and if this program is only using one file.

Answer (score 4):

A global variable has *external* linkage by default. Meaning, it can be accessed by other translation units by using `extern`.

Declaring a global variable as `static` gives it *internal* linkage. Meaning, it can only be accessed within the translation unit that it is declared in, `extern` can't reach it.

If the program only has 1  translation unit (`.c`/`.cpp` file), declaring a global variable in that unit as `static` doesn't make any difference. But, if you have multiple translation units, it starts to make more sense to declare globals as `static` when you don't want to share them across translation units.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration for more details.

Comment: I see, most of my programs are using only 1 .cpp file, along with .hpp header files as needed so I don't need the static keyword for global variables for now.